# Conflict when make dynamic routing in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm new in Laravel. I want to make routing in Laravel.

- `domain/{member_name} -> to MemberController`
- `domain/{admin_name} -> to AdminController`

But when I access `domain/example-admin-name`, it only goes to `MemberController`.

I know I can make `domain/member/{member_name}` and `domain/admin/{admin_name}`.

But I want it to be simple and only have one segment URI

Comment: But how do you know the difference between member routes and admin routes?

Comment: set up one method that will accept the request and decides which view should it return

Comment: If you only have one segment that is variable you can only use one controller function

Comment: This problem has been solved.. thanks...

Answer (score 0):

laravel routes initialize two routes as a one, because dont find any difference between them,so you can do this in two approach
1. use a prefix for your routes such as:

```
domain/users/{member_name} -> to MemberController
domain/admin/{admin_name} -> to AdminController
```

2.use one routes and handle destinition with user role in your controller function, for example if your login user has role 1 show admin panel and if has role 2 redirect to user panel

I advice first solution, because you have better and optimize codes.

Answer (score 0):

Create just one route `domain/{username}` -> `UserController`

In your `UserController->__invoke()` function, do a check if the user is a member or an admin with your logic. You could write a class for that if you want, if you don't want to put this logic directly in the controller.

Then when you know what kind of user you're dealing with, pass the data to a `MemberHandler` or an `AdminHandler` class. These could return some values to the controller which you pass on to the view, or you could do a redirect depending on the return value.

To make it **dynamically** you could do something like this: (but of course you could also build if-else constructs for choosing the correct Handler and View, which would help your IDE knowing which classes you actually use).

```
public function __invoke(Request $request, $username){

    // return 'Member' or 'Admin'
    $userType = $this->getUserType($username);

    // break out of function if userType is invalid
    if(!$userType){
        return 'cannot match usertype';
    }

    // compile the fully qualified class name for your handler
    // this should produce \App\MyClasses\MemberHandler or \App\MyClasses\AdminHandler respectively
    $targetHandlerClass = '\\App\\MyClasses\\' . $userType . 'Handler';

    // instantiate your dynamically picked user handler
    $handler = new $targetHandlerClass($username);

    $data = $handler->doSomething();

    // calls the view named 'Member.blade.php' or 'Admin.blade.php'
    return view($userType, compact($data));
}
```